# Matplotlib FigureCanvasTkAgg not detecting keypress after using Tk Spinbox widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, focus, tkinter-entry

I am making use of Tkinter and matplotlib to write a image clipping tool. An image is displayed using matplotlib embedded on a Tkinter canvas (FigureCanvasTkAgg). The user will then be able to place 4 points on the image. A point is placed by holding shift and left clicking the mouse. A right mouse press will delete the point.
A polygon connecting the 4 points is then drawn. The user can extrude each side of the polygon by changing the values in the Tkinter Spinbox widgets.

And here is the problem. If the entry box part of the Spinbox is used, this takes focus from the canvas/matplotlib figure/axis. I'm then unable to place any more points because although the mouse left clicks are detected, the press of the shift key is no longer detected!

I've tried to remove most unnecessary code.
The path to an image file is hard coded on line 205, you'll need to change this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Jan 18 20:28:52 2017

Sample of a script which is used to crop an image at user placed points.
The user will place 4 points on the displayed image.
A quadrangle will then be created by joining the 4 points. 
Each side of the quadrangle can be extruded by changing the 'buffer values'.

Instructions:
Hold shift and left click on image to place a new point.
Right click to delete a point.
"""
from __future__ import division

import Tkinter as Tk

# Matplotlib (mpl) - for plotting data/arrays/images.
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib import figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler


class MyApp(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        # Drawing points and lines class
        self.Vectors = Vectors(parent_class=self)

        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.wm_title("Sample Script!")
        # Position of top-left corner of the app. (from left side of screen, from top of screen).
        self.master.geometry("+100+10")

        self.frame1 = Tk.Frame(self.master) # Canvas 1
        self.frame1.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

        self.frame2 = Tk.Frame(self.master) # Buttons
        self.frame2.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

        self.fig = figure.Figure(dpi=110)#plt.figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.ax1.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
        self.ax1.grid(True)
        self.ax1.autoscale(True)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.frame1)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        # Events
        # keyboard events on the canvas (image)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_canvas_key_press)
        # mouse click events on the canvas (image/plot)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_button_canvas1)
        # clicking on drawn artists events:
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick_canvas1)

        # Mouse Events
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('figure_enter_event', self.enter_figure)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('figure_leave_event', self.leave_figure)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('axes_enter_event', self.enter_axes)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('axes_leave_event', self.leave_axes)

        self.cursor_x = None
        self.cursor_y = None
        # targest lines on ax1 at cursor position.
        self.ax1_hline = None
        self.ax1_vline = None

        # add the matplotlib navigation toolbar, connected to the canvas.
        self.add_toolbar() # add the Navigation toolbar for this canvas

        # add the GUI for editing the rectangle buffer.
        self.buffer_settings(self.frame2)

        # Buttont which displays the test image.
        Button_TestImage = Tk.Button(self.frame2,
                                     text="test_disp_image()",
                                     command = self.test_disp_image)
        Button_TestImage.pack()

    def add_toolbar(self):
        """ Add the matplotlib inbuilt Navigation toolbar
        http://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html """
        #self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self.frame1)
        self.toolbar = CustomToolbar(self.canvas, self.frame1)        

    def buffer_settings(self, frame):
        """ GUI for setting buffer distance for each line around clipping
        quadrangle. """
        self.buf_frame = Tk.Frame(frame)
        self.buf_frame.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

        self.spinbox_frame = Tk.Frame(frame)
        self.spinbox_frame.pack(side=Tk.RIGHT)

        # Buffer settings:
        self.buf_N = Tk.IntVar()
        self.buf_N.set(50)
        self.buf_N.trace('w', self.buff_callback)

        self.buf_E = Tk.IntVar()
        self.buf_E.set(140)
        self.buf_E.trace('w', self.buff_callback)

        self.buf_S = Tk.IntVar()
        self.buf_S.set(50)
        self.buf_S.trace('w', self.buff_callback)


        self.buf_W = Tk.IntVar()
        self.buf_W.set(250)
        self.buf_W.trace('w', self.buff_callback)

        # spinbox selector for each buffer selection.
        n = Tk.Spinbox(self.spinbox_frame, from_=-1000, to=1000,
                       textvariable=self.buf_N)
        n.grid(row=1, column=1)
        w = Tk.Spinbox(self.spinbox_frame, from_=-1000, to=1000,
                       textvariable=self.buf_W)
        w.grid(row=2, column=0)
        e = Tk.Spinbox(self.spinbox_frame, from_=-1000, to=1000,
                       textvariable=self.buf_E)
        e.grid(row=2, column=2)
        s = Tk.Spinbox(self.spinbox_frame, from_=-1000, to=1000,
                       textvariable=self.buf_S)
        s.grid(row=3, column=1)


    def buff_callback(self, *args):
        print "variable changed!"
        self.update_polygon()

    def update_polygon(self):
        """ update buffered polygon when buffer distance is changed"""
        # TODO - update polygon using adjusted bufer values
        # Get buffer spinbox values
        n, e, s, w = self.get_buffer_settings()
        print "n, e, s, w", n, e, s, w

    def get_buffer_settings(self):
        """ get the buffer spinbox values """
        n = self.buf_N.get()
        e = self.buf_E.get()
        s = self.buf_S.get()
        w = self.buf_W.get()
        return (n, e, s, w)

    def on_canvas_key_press(self, event):
        print "on_canvas_key_press()"
        key_press_handler(event, self.canvas, self.toolbar)

    def on_pick_canvas1(self, event):
        """
        This func called when an artist is picked on  canvas 1
        i.e. clicked on a point.
        If multiple overlapping artists are picked, this func will be call
        for each one."""
        print "on_pick_canvas1()"
        if event.mouseevent.inaxes is not None and not hasattr(event, 'already_picked'):
            mouseevent = event.mouseevent

            if mouseevent.button == 3:
                # delete point.
                print "delete point!"
                for saved_point_artist in self.Vectors.points:
                    if saved_point_artist.contains(mouseevent)[0] == True:
                        # remove the point from the canvas
                        saved_point_artist.remove()
                        # delete the saved artist from the list
                        self.Vectors.points.remove(saved_point_artist)
                        # Update the canvas
                        self.canvas.draw()
        return

    def on_button_canvas1(self, event):
        """ mouse button events on the canvas.
        http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent"""
        print "on_button_canvas1()"
        button = event.button
        key = event.key
        print "button, key", button, key
        if event.inaxes is not None:
            # image pixel position (centre of pixel)
            x, y = (event.xdata, event.ydata)
            # offset to corner of pixel
            x, y = x + 0.5, y + 0.5
            print x,y
            print('button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
              (event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata, ))
            # process left click
            if button == 1:
                # hold shift to draw a point.
                if key == 'shift':
                    self.Vectors.new_box_point(x, y)
                    self.canvas.draw()
        return

    def test_disp_image(self):
        """ read and display a .jpg image file."""
        img_path = r"C:\Scripts\parade_dog.jpg"
        # read image
        self.im = matplotlib.image.imread(img_path)
        self.ax1.imshow(self.im)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def enter_axes(self, event):
        print('enter_axes', event.inaxes)

    def leave_axes(self, event):
        print('leave_axes', event.inaxes)

    def enter_figure(self, event):
        print('enter_figure', event.canvas.figure)

    def leave_figure(self, event):
        print('leave_figure', event.canvas.figure)


class Vectors:
    def __init__(self, parent_class):
        self.parent = parent_class # the plotting class
        self.points = []

    def new_box_point(self, x, y):
        """ master new point funtion"""
        # draw a point on the canvas, and save point to list.
        point_artist = self.draw_point(x, y)
        self.points.append(point_artist)

    def draw_point(self, x, y):
        centre = (x,y)
        fluro_green = (0.271, 0.99, 0.271)# equivalent to (70,250, 70)
        point = matplotlib.patches.Circle(xy=centre, radius=5,
                                             edgecolor=fluro_green,
                                             facecolor=fluro_green,
                                             fill=True,
                                             visible=True,
                                             picker=15)
        self.parent.ax1.add_patch(point)
        return point # return the artist.


class CustomToolbar(NavigationToolbar2TkAgg):
    def __init__(self,canvas_,parent_):
        self.toolitems = (
            ('Home', "Reset original view\n\
            ('h' or 'r')", 'home', 'home'),
            ('Back', "previous view\n\
            ('c' or 'left arrow' or 'backspace')", 'back', 'back'),
            ('Forward', "next view\n\
            ('v' or 'left arrow')", 'forward', 'forward'),
            (None, None, None, None),
            ('Pan', "Pan axis (left mouse), Zoom (right mouse).\n\
            ('p')", 'move', 'pan'),
            ('Zoom', "Zoom box\n\
            ('o')", 'zoom_to_rect', 'zoom'),
            (None, None, None, None),
#            ('Subplots', 'Configure subplots axis', 'subplots', 'configure_subplots'),
            ('Save', 'Save plot', 'filesave', 'save_figure'),
            )
        NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.__init__(self,canvas_,parent_)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing ingredient here was using `get_tk_widget()` to access the canvas widget, which then allowed me to us the `focus_force()` function to change focus from the Entry widget to the canvas.

e.g.

```
self.fig.canvas.get_tk_widget().focus_force()
```